# Pointing, two or more archived Blog posts to the same permalink (Single post page)

Tags: permalinks

Can two or more posts in an archive each point/link to the same single post page (permalink). If so, how do I achieves this.

Comment: How are you going to differentiate between two posts if they have the same permalink

Comment: Here is the scenario.

1.Click ‘Portfolio’ from navigation
2.Here are the categories shown on the archive page that you can filter through  “Red”, “Blue”, “Green”, “Yellow”, "All"
3.That portfolio archive page displays the final images,not the 'featured image' for the post.
4.Click on 1 image which takes you to the single post page of that project with the project gallery.

This way people are NOT sorting by project, but rather by the type of images they want to see. Once they click into the image they like, they see more about that particular project (and the other images from that project).

Comment: So the Images in the archive will each have a custom link to a Single page post. Several images in the archive can link to the same single post page. How would I go about customizing the links pointing to specific posts

Comment: File an [edit] and add all that info in your question where it belongs ;-)